# JAVA: Map.put(K, K V), doesn't Maps only have 2 values?

Tags: java, dictionary

So I started programming 2 months ago, this maybe obvious but I have no idea how I could even google my question.

```
Map<Character,Integer> characters = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char c = word.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        if(characters.containsKey(c)) {
            characters.put(c,characters.get(c) + 1);
        } else {
            characters.put(c,1);
        }
    }
```

In the 4th line, I put a Character, then a Character **and** Integer pair into the map.

Doesn't the .put method require exactly **2 values** (Key and Value)?

Comment: Think of `characters.get(c) + 1` as something like `int x = characters.get(c) + 1`. Now you only put the value of `x` into the map (with some auto-boxing) to `Integer`. A method to put 2 values would look like `put(c, characters.get(c), 1)`  (note the second comma) - does that look like it would make sense? :)

Comment: Btw, your code's performance could be improved by doing something like this: `Integer existing = characters.get(c); if(existing != null) { characters.put(c, existing + 1); } ...` - no need to do the lookup twice. This can be further reduced by using the `merge()` method and a method reference: `characters.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum );` would replace the entire if-else block (`Integer::sum` is a method reference and in your case would be equivalent to the lambda `(existing, added) -> existing + added`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stil using two arguments in this line.

```
characters.put(c,characters.get(c) + 1);
```

The second argument is the operation `characters.get(c) + 1` that results in a single integer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!